# OpenGL: Model stretched when translated from origin

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a space flight simulator as my first real OpenGL project. I'm having trouble getting a cube to render properly when it isn't located at the origin. What happens is that the cube stretches out from the origin, and the degree of stretching depends on the amount translated from the origin.

I believe that it has nothing to do with the shader, as I have tried two different vertex shaders with the same result. one of the shaders is a very simple shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){    

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

    // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    fragmentColor = vec3(255,255,255);
}
```

It seems pretty clear to me that the problem is not with the shader.

When the cube translated by 1 unit in each direction, it looks like this:

[image]

When translating the camera in the positive Z direction, the cube will stretch more to follow the camera.

**Before translating** (camera located at (0,0,25) and model located at (5,5,5))

MVP Matrix:

```
(10.942525, 0.000000, 12.402489, 12.500000)   
(0.000000, 14.590034, 12.402489, 12.500000)   
(0.000000, 0.000000, 12.302468, 12.400000)   
(0.000000, 0.000000, 24.804977, 25.000000)
```

Transformation Matrix:

```
(0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000)   
(0.000000, 0.100000, 0.000000, 0.500000)   
(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.100000, 0.500000)   
(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000)
```

[image]

**After translating** (camera translated in the positive z direction)

Transformation Matrix:

```
(0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000)
(0.000000, 0.100000, 0.000000, 0.500000)
(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.100000, 0.500000)
(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000)
```

MVP Matrix:

```
(10.942525, 0.000000, 46.159237, 46.250000)
(0.000000, 14.590034, 46.159237, 46.250000)
(0.000000, 0.000000, 46.059216, 46.150002)
(0.000000, 0.000000, 92.318474, 92.500000)
```

[image]

Here's my code for getting the transformation matrices from the models:

```
glm::mat4 MovableObject::getTransformationMatrix() const
{
    return getTranslationMatrix() * getRotationMatrix() * getScaleMatrix();
}

glm::mat4 MovableObject::getScaleMatrix() const
{
    glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    scaleMatrix[0][0] = scaleFactors[0];
    scaleMatrix[1][1] = scaleFactors[1];
    scaleMatrix[2][2] = scaleFactors[2];
    return scaleMatrix;
}

glm::mat4 MovableObject::getRotationMatrix() const
{
    return glm::toMat4(rotation);
}

glm::mat4 MovableObject::getTranslationMatrix() const
{
    glm::mat4 translationMatrix = glm::mat4(1.);
    translationMatrix[0][3] = center[0];
    translationMatrix[1][3] = center[1];
    translationMatrix[2][3] = center[2];
    return translationMatrix;
}
```

here's the rendering code for drawing the mesh:

```
void Mesh::render(glm::mat4 modelMatrix, const Camera& camera)
{
    glUseProgram(programID);

    glm::mat4 view = camera.getViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 pvm = camera.getProjectionMatrix() * view * modelMatrix;

    std::cout << "MVP Matrix: " << glm::to_string(pvm) << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader,
    // in the "MVP" uniform
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &pvm[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &modelMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);

    glUniform3f(lightID, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f); // TODO: hardwiring at 0 for now

    // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    // Set "myTextureSampler" sampler to user Texture Unit 0
    glUniform1i(textureID, 0);

    // 1st attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                          0,                  // attribute
                          3,                  // size
                          GL_FLOAT,           // type
                          GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                          0,                  // stride
                          (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                          );

    // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                          1,                                // attribute
                          2,                                // size
                          GL_FLOAT,                         // type
                          GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
                          0,                                // stride
                          (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
                          );

    // 3rd attribute buffer : normals
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                          2,                                // attribute
                          3,                                // size
                          GL_FLOAT,                         // type
                          GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
                          0,                                // stride
                          (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
                          );

    // Draw the triangles !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size() );

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
}
```

and here's the code for getting the camera matrices:

```
glm::mat4 Camera::getProjectionMatrix() const
{
    return glm::perspective(FoV, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
}

glm::mat4 Camera::getViewMatrix() const
{
    glm::mat4 matrix = glm::toMat4(rotation);
    glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(matrix[0][1], matrix[1][1], matrix[2][1]);
    glm::vec3 forward = -glm::vec3(matrix[0][2], matrix[1][2], matrix[2][2]);


    return glm::lookAt(center, center + forward, up);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i am not understanding this correctly and had a couple of questions - why is your MVP looking so different in the two cases when you are **translating only** along z-axis? Also to which matrix is this translation being added to? Your model matrix seems constant across both cases and  'Camera::getViewMatrix()' doesn't seem to be using translation at all??

Comment: The translation is being added to the matrix representing the camera, so the camera is moving, not the model. I think that might be why the MVP looks so different, but honestly I am not sure.

Comment: Also, center represents the vector for the center of the camera or model, so getViewMatrix() uses that translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glm uses column-major storage order, so you'll have to access elements as m[col][row]. Your `getTranslationMatrix()` function is not following that convention, as the translation vector should be in the last column. Your code printing the numbers of your matrices seems to interpret the contents transposed, too.

Please note that glm alread has functionality to create transformation matrices like rotation, scaling and translation via the [`GLM_GTX_transform` module](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00296.html).

Comment: See, this is what happens when I dither looking for other potential problems in the code.  I get beaten to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to assume there's a problem with your functions that are directly accessing members of the matrix

```
glm::mat4 MovableObject::getScaleMatrix() const {
  glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
  scaleMatrix[0][0] = scaleFactors[0];
  scaleMatrix[1][1] = scaleFactors[1];
  scaleMatrix[2][2] = scaleFactors[2];
  return scaleMatrix;
}

glm::mat4 MovableObject::getTranslationMatrix() const
{
  glm::mat4 translationMatrix = glm::mat4(1.);
  translationMatrix[0][3] = center[0];
  translationMatrix[1][3] = center[1];
  translationMatrix[2][3] = center[2];
  return translationMatrix;
}
```

Why are you doing this instead of the much safer

```
glm::mat4 MovableObject::getScaleMatrix() const {
  return glm::scale(glm::mat4(), scaleFactors);
}

glm::mat4 MovableObject::getTranslationMatrix() const {
  return glm::translate(glm::mat4(), center);
}
```